# Synaptics driver under Wayland?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics, wayland

I've recently installed 17.10 on my Acer Aspire V5 and had some trouble with the touchpad. It is not precise at all. It is really hard to hit small buttons or checkboxes. I've used the libinput debugger to confirm that the absolute pixelmovements somehow look like this:

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
5.68
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

Meaning the device recognizes input, but doesn't move the mouse (in one axis at least) and then suddenly jumps like 5 pixels. If I move my mouse diagonally it follows a stair like patter, like no anti-aliasing if that makes sense.
[Here is a webm I found that shows what's happening although the frame-rate is a bit low.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1074920)

The device is a synaptics Touchpad. The problem is, I don't know how to install the synaptics driver for wayland. I can only find `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` which is obviously for xorg not for wayland.

I hope someone can help me with this because it's driving me (and anyone who tries to use my laptop) insane within minutes.

Comment: try to login to xorg session instead of wayland

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, but in the new Ubuntu 20.04.4 version it seems fixed to me.